# Combining heredoc with pipe fails

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to log into an API, using curl. Because the request expects JSON, I'm using this:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    $API_URL/auth -d@- <<EOF
{
  "id": "$USER@example.com",
  "password": "!password!"
}
EOF
```

...and that's working fine. I get a result that looks something like this:

```
{"access_token":"jXed...I5mQ=","expires_in":3600}
```

But when I attempt to capture the output in a variable, it doesn't work.

I've tried:

```
x=$(curl ...)
```

...but that fails with `bash: !password!: event not found`

Yes, my password *does* start with a `!`; this is a test installation of the API, so I'm using a weak password.

I'm aware that if I use `set +H`, or run this from a script, bash won't do anything with the `!`. My problem is that:

1. I occasionally want to copy-paste the script into the command line.  In six months time, I'll have forgotten about this wrinkle.
2. Why is bash even attempting to do this inside a heredoc?

Because of the aforementioned weirdness with `!`, I tried piping the results to `read` instead:

```
(curl ...
EOF
) | read x
```

...but then it mangles the heredoc somehow, and the server responds with the equivalent of "invalid JSON".

If I use `cat` instead of `curl`, the heredoc appears to be empty, incidentally.

Comment: I've tried just `cat` and the heredoc and can't reproduce this behaviour, using *GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release* on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `event not found` error, just use `set +H`, including in the script. It's harmless, and you can add a comment explaining it.

`| read x` simply doesn't work; see http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ, specifically:

> E4) If I pipe the output of a command into `read variable', why doesn't
>       the output show up in $variable when the read command finishes?

In bash, the `| foo` runs `foo` in a subshell. It can't change variables in the parent shell.

Use `x=$(whatever)`  instead.